# How to display Visual Studio loadtest result file (.trx) into readable format?

Tags: html, performance, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, trx

I would like to execute my load tests on the regular basis and make it part of my CI process.

I'd like to run a Visual Studio loadtest from the console and provide the results of the test in human readable format (preferably HTML page).

For executing the test I use **MSTest.exe** util which produces **.trx** file to specified location.

e.g.

```
mstest /TestContainer:LoadTest.loadtest /resultsfile:c:\Temp\MyResults.trx
```

My problem is to convert this **.trx** file into something which can be displayed in browser.

I tried several tools mentioned in another topics like **trx2html** converters and so on. All of them were built for conversion of unit tests and fail to convert load test results correctly.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What do you expect to see in your report? The ".trx" file is just XML, have you looked in the file to see whether it contains the sort of data you want in your report? The main results of a load test are stored in and SQL database, the ".trx" file contains information to access the relevant sections of the database.

Comment: Actually yes, this is a good point @AdrianHHH!  I needed 95% time for several requests, but making reports from DB is where I ended up. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Hi Pavel, Whould you like to share your approach to generate reports from the (localdb)\v11.0 DB

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135374/using-keys-in-xslt-for-converting-trx-file-of-mstest

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the "archive artifacts" option in Jenkins for the **/*.trx file(s). That way you can click on the link and the trx file will open in Visual Studio.

Of course that means this is only of use to people with Visual Studio installed.